# Write to text file with workflow

Tags: workflow

I am attempting to write a workflow, that extracts some fields from my list, (the filenames) and write those to a text file, so that I can then merge the pdf documents that are taken from the list. I do not have much C# experience, and have written the workflow in SPD, although it is limiting me to only be able to email those results. Can somebody help me write a custom workflow, so that I can get to the next step and merge the documents?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to write to a file using the Out-Of-The-Box SharePoint Designer activities. You will either need to create your own Custom Workflow Activity in Visual Studio or use a 3rd party product such as the [Workflow Power Pack](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/Workflow-Power-Pack-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) that allows VB or C# code to be added directly to SharePoint Designer workflows.

Providing the service account's privileges allow this, you will be able to write to the file system of the server or UNC path this way.

Note that I work for the company that has developed the Workflow Power Pack so consider me biased :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't an existing custom Workflow Activity already built, here are some on CodePlex.com that might help out.

[CodePlex.com-Workflow Activities](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?ProjectSearchText=workflow%20activities)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to do from a business perspective? You have multiple PDFs and you want to be able to merge them into...(?)  It's possible that the SharePoint Web Services can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

@Marc: Im trying to merge the 10 or so documents into a single document. And want a Merge Button on each page that contains those 10 documents. The Merge button should be dynamic, and be able to grab the fields that contain the 10 PDF's and then display or save the single pdf.

@Muhimbi: your site is down

Comment: Haven't had any reports of the site being down, must have been a blip. Can you try again?

Comment: @Tom: Move this answer into a comment on Marc's question and he will be notified of your query. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Aspose.Words for SharePoint](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/73/sharepoint-components/aspose.words-for-sharepoint/default.aspx) solution if you just need to combine several office files into single PDF. Running under MOSS 2010 you'll be able to select desired files right in the library and create combined file just in couple clicks.